# authentication process, why store sessionID in database?

Tags: php, android, authentication

I have a question about the NORMAL PROCESS OF AUTHENTICATION.

I have google a lot, and read a lot, but still can not very clear about the process of authentication, 
what is actually the sessionID? 
Why we store sessionID in database, because I think session ID will some time be expired. why we still need to store them?
What if I use OAuth for android App or desktop App?

More explanation:

1. For example, I use Form to login in. User send "userName" and "passWord", and then I use MD5($passWord), and then send all of them to server URI, is that right?
2. Then Server get userName and passWord, and then compare the passWord with the passWord in database, if the same, then right. Server send back the SessionId to user, the cookie will be set. Is the process right?
3. If it is right, the server will store sessionID in database, but sessionId will expire some time, why we store the session ID in database?

Comment: When you store the session handling via database then you need to store the id also in database. Usually session is stored on disk. BTW don't use MD5 as a hash method for passwords, it's insecure by now.

Comment: Instead using MD5, use SHA1. I can post a snippet of code to use it. Tell me if you need it

Answer (score 1):

1. When you are dealing with secure data, you should use SSL (https). Doing an MD5 on the password is rather pointless. If I grabbed the traffic, I could un-MD5 it with brute force an/or a rainbow table. MD5 is not for security. It is for identifying large blocks of data with a much smaller block of data.
2. You shouldn't store the password in the database. You should store a salted hash of the password in your database. Then, you salt and hash the password the user sends and see if it matches what is in the database. Again, don't use MD5. Use a better (longer) hash - and make sure it is salted.
3. The server needs to know which sessions are open and in use. So, it has to store them. You don't need to store the session ID. The server does. When the session expires, the server deletes the session.

Comment: Thank you all!                                                                                          I am very new to authentication, I actually not know the process.

Comment: Thank you all!            I am very new to authentication, I actually not know the process. @kainaw. 1 - if I do not use MD5, then what is better? Like SHA-256? 2 - Befor I use SSL to transfer the passWord and userName, should I need to crypto-hash the data, and then use SSL or just use SSL? 3 - How do I know, which session is to whom. I should use Session ID or ? Why I see some websites, after I login in, there is SessionID in cookie?

Comment: If you use SSL, you don't need to hash anything. If I crack the SSL encryption, the hash will be trivial to undo. When storing a password hash, use a hash with a lot of bits (like SHA-256 or better). You never need to know what the session ID is. The server automatically segregates the sessions for you. When you use $_SESSION, it is the current user's session.

Comment: very clear, thank you @Answers_Seeker. I have one more question about sessionId, 1 - Server received the hased password, and then hash it again, then store it to database? Two times hashed? 2 - What information should I use to generate a SessionID?

Comment: @ kainaw, Okay, clear. what I need to do is just hash the trasfered passWord, the compare with database passWord,  right? Then should I also set cookie = sessionID?  If in the destop App or Android App, how to handle the session and cookies?

Comment: Because you are asking in reference to PHP, I am answering in reference to PHP. PHP handles the session for you. It sets the ID. It sets the Cookie. It reads the Cookie. It loads the session each time you need it. You don't do any session management at all. All you do is call `session_start()` and then you use `$_SESSION` as an array.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I use Form to login in. User send "userName" and "passWord", and then I use MD5($passWord), and then send all of them to server URI, is that right?

Not. Md5 is a weak hash algorithm, there are other ones which are safer. Other than that, the hash you produce should be more complex than just

```
hash('whatever_algorithm', $password)
```

There are libraries like PHPass and functions like password_hash which will help you.

As a protocol, you should use SSL and go for **https**.

> Then Server get userName and passWord, and then compare the passWord with the passWord in database, if the same, then right. Server send back the SessionId to user, the cookie will be set. Is the process right?

The process is wrong since you shouldn't keep clear credentials data in your database, it's the credentials' hash which should be stored and you should try to reproduce it using the username + password given by the user. 
The hash is an asymetric algorithm : it goes only one way.

You can harden the security by adding some authentication steps on the session which follow a specific expected input/output exchange.

> If it is right, the server will store sessionID in database, but sessionId will expire some time, why we store the session ID in database?

You store the sessionID while it's alive(not timeouted) so the user can still connect without needing to reauthenticate. 
When the session returned an Error Code, you keep its ID in the database in order to have a track on relevant information and be able to produce logs.
You can, for instance:

- add the client's IP in your session table so you can track the **WHO**.
- add error_codes linked to your session so you can track the **WHAT**
- add a datetime to the table to see the **WHEN**

If an error happened during a session, you might need to know the reason(someone trying to bypass your session security or errors from your implementation of the session).